# Clojure REPL forgets classpath

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I'm a bit of a Clojure newbie and something in the REPL is really confusing me.

I have a project called "misc" and a namespace at "misc/src/counter_window.clj". When I do enter the REPL from the project root folder I want to import counter_window's functions, but I seem to have to go through the following weird tango every time:

```
user=> (use 'counter-window)
FileNotFoundException Could not locate counter_window__init.class or counter_window.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.  clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:449)

user=> (use 'misc.counter-window)

CompilerException java.lang.Exception: namespace 'misc.counter-window' not found after loading '/misc/counter_window', compiling:(/tmp/form-init2530455467319465680.clj:1:1) 
user=> (use 'counter-window)
nil ;; the import succeeds this third time.
```

The warning in the FileNotFound exception doesn't seem to apply because the namespace is called `counter-window` in the counter_window.clj file already.

So why does this happen? Why does the import not work the first time, but then succeed the third time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a direct relation between file path and the namespace. A file `src/counter_window.clj` ought to have the namespace declaration `(ns counter-window)`.

A namespace `misc.counter-window` should be defined in the file `src/misc/counter_window.clj`. ie it will have the form `(ns misc.counter-window)`. Note that `misc` is a folder inside `src`. Your project could be named anything, I don't think it would affect the namespaces.

Assuming what you wanted was the namespace `misc.counter-window` and your file is correspondingly at `src/misc/counter_window.clj`, the following works in the repl

```
(use '[misc.counter-window])
```

Comment: I was missing the `misc.` in the namespace!